# ¿Se puede evaluar un string mediante un método en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, método, evaluación

Al escribir código surgió un problema con un string mientras iba moviendo el cursor en la consola:

```
"2+2".
     ^
     |
```

Estoy indicando la flecha hacia arriba, en el momento en que escribí el punto para obtener los métodos de un string... Quise resolver esta operación, pero sin moverme hacia la izquierda.

Si lo resuelvo con `eval`, tengo que moverme a la izquierda para escribir un paréntesis de apertura, y luego acordarme la posición donde estaba, y escribir un paréntesis de cierre.

```
"2+2"
    ^
"2+2"
   ^
"2+2"
  ^
"2+2"
 ^
"2+2"
^
eval("2+2"
    ^
eval("2+2"
     ^
eval("2+2"
      ^
eval("2+2"
       ^
eval("2+2"
        ^
eval("2+2"
         ^
eval("2+2")
          ^
```

Lo que me vendría mejor es algo como lo siguiente:

```
"2+2".aplicar(eval)
```

De esta manera no tengo que ir y volver con el cursor.

Es algo tedioso, entonces la pregunta es, ¿Existe un método nativo que aplique métodos para un string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un método en el prototipo de la clase String, de tal manera que todos los nuevos objetos de la clase String que se creen a continuación van a tener ese método.

Este método aceptaría como parámetro la función a ejecutar, y lo que haría es ejecutar la función que has pasado como parámetro (fun), pasándole a su vez el string de entrada (this).

```js
String.prototype.aplicar = function(fun) {
    return fun(this.toString());
}

console.log("2+2".aplicar(eval));
```

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: Solo sería necesario aclarar que `eval` tiene sus peligros y lo ideal sería evitar su uso mientras sea posible.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es usar `split` para convertir el string a un array de caracteres, luego usar `map`, que acepta una función como parámetro, se ejecuta la función creando el prototipo, y luego con `join` se vuelve a unir los caracteres.

1. Con `split` convierte a un array de caracteres.
2. Con `map` ejecuta la función para crear el prototipo si no existe.
3. Con `join` une nuevamente los caracteres.
4. Se ejecuta la función `aplicar` con `eval`.

De esta manera no hay que crear el prototipo antes, si no que después del string, usando puramente métodos.

Código:

```js
console.log("2+2"
    .split("")
    .map(x=>[
        x,
        !x.aplicar&&(
            x.__proto__.aplicar = function(x){
                return x(this.toString())
            }
        )
    ])
    .map(x=>x[0])
    .join("")
    .aplicar(eval)
)
```

Otra manera simple es usar `split` sin parámetros, de esta manera genera un array de un solo elemento.

```
"2+2".split() // ["2+2"]
  .map(x=>eval(x)) // [4]
  [0] // 4
```

Se ejecuta el `eval` dentro del map y el primer elemento del array (`[0]`) es el resultado.

Código:

```js
console.log(
  "2+2".split().map(x=>eval(x))[0]
)
```